# Ansible set flag (var) in role and re-use it

Tags: ansible

I want to use my role twice. Is it possible to set some flag during the first execution in the role and read it on the second?

For example (main.yml):

```
---
hosts: all
...

pre_tasks:
...

roles:
- role: maintenance

- role: something1
  vars:
    ...

- role: something2
  vars:
    ...

- role: maintenance
```

I want to run role `maintenance` twice, in this role I will have conditions for several tasks, these conditions will depend on my flag variable:

- first execution will process all tasks and will set flag var to true (for example)
- second execution will skip part of tasks due to flag condition

Yes, I know, that I can pass "my flag var" in `vars` for `maintenance` task, but it is more elegant for me to not send it twice in vara and use it inside role if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this by setting a fact. These are associated with the host, rather than the role in which they were created, and therefore can be checked during the execution of subsequent roles.

Try this inside your `maintenance` role:

```yaml
- block

    # Insert tasks to be skipped inside the block here

    - name: Set flag to mark as already processed
      set_fact:
        already_processed: true
      check_mode: false

  when: already_processed is not defined or not already_processed
```

A couple of notes:

- the `check_mode: false` ensures that if you run the playbook in check mode, this fact will actually be actually be set, ensuring the correct behaviour. If you don't have this, the fact will not get set in check mode
- `or not already_processed` in the `when` condition is technically not required. With this basic example, the `already_processed` variable will not exist until the first pass through the maintenance role. I however, like to spell out the behaviour explicitly, as later down the road I may want to pre-define the `already_processed` variable ahead of time and so this will continue to work as expected